# Re-writing the root

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Is it possible to rewrite the root ?

For example;
domain.co.uk/ rewrites in the address bar as domain.co.uk/home/

/home/ already being a rewrite of index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, redirecting to `/home`. Even though `/home` later rewrites as `index.php`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /home [L,R=301]
```